# TikZ: How to draw in a 'path picture' environment outside of the 'path picture bounding box'

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to draw outside of the `path picture bounding box` if drawing into a `path picture` environment?  (For theoretical interest.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
\fill[yellow] (0,0) circle(10pt);
\fill[orange] (3,4) circle(10pt);

\node[draw, thick, minimum size=3cm,
path picture={
\fill[red, overlay] (path picture bounding box.west) coordinate(X1) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (3,4) circle(3pt);% not shown
},
]{a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you don't write `\fill[red] (3,4) circle(3pt);` outside of `path picture`? (If I understand your problem)

Comment: Did you read the comment: "For theoretical interest"?

Comment: What about this: `\node[draw, thick, minimum size=3cm]{a}[path picture={
  \fill[red, overlay] (path picture bounding box.west) coordinate(X1) circle(2pt);
  \fill[red] (3,2) circle(3pt);}];`

Comment: That seems to be good. :)